# Trignometric formulas for compound angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I know and understand the formulas for sin(a+b), cos(a+b), etc. and how they're geometrically proven.

I tried to derive a formula for sin(a+b+c) just to begin with couldn't really get anywhere, can anyone attempt this problem and share a solution?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Deriving multi-angle addition sin formulaes"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4150132/409). See, in particular, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4150155/409).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving multi-angle addition sin formulaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4150132/deriving-multi-angle-addition-sin-formulaes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating $\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447364/evaluating-cos-alpha-beta-gamma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If $x = b+c$ then
$$
\sin(a+b+c) = \sin(a+x)
$$
and you can apply the usual sine expansion. When you are done, you will have the result in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, but
$$
\sin(x) = \sin(b+c)
$$
and you can apply the expansion again. Ditto with the cosine.

Please feel free to post results of your work below in comments or update your question for further guidance.